# How to send null data by JQuery AJAX ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, null

I am trying to send the null data by JQuery AJAX. However, I end up getting an error message which says "Bad Request". I have tried using the word "null" to send to the database, however, this has not worked. The database does allow for nulls. I can manually add data directly into the database while inputting no data in the null columns.

```
                $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:58371/api/ScheduleDateAndTime',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "startDateAndTime": startTotalTimeAndDate,
                    "endDateAndTime": endTotalTimeAndDate,
                    "studentId": studentIdSelected,
                    "staffId": staffIdSelected
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("You have assigned staff member " + staffSelected + " to student " + studentSelected + " on " +  datePickerValue   + " starting at " + startTime + " and ending at "  + endTime);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError + " have you checked that you have selected a date in the calander?\n Please ensure all fields have been correctly entered");
                }
            });
```

I want to be able to send null data on the "studentId" column in the database. "studentId" is a variable that gets its data from a drop-down list, where one of the available options is "none", which has "null" as its id.

Comment: If you're getting a 400 response when you send `null` for that value, then it sounds like your ASP logic is not configured correctly to allow nulls. In that case you would need to amend the ASP code, not your JS. Also, be sure that you're sending an actual `null` value, not the word in a string, eg `'null'`.

Comment: I just tried it via postman REST client and it didn't work, so it seems you're right that the problem is in the asp.net logic. I have allowed nullable in the model, here is that code "public int? staffId { get; set; } ", however, the connection is done by api. I have added the api code as well

Comment: Glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 3):

The ASP.NET DTO model did not allow for nulls, once this was changed to the following I was then able to upload nulls

```
public int? studentId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont send the value that should be null

```
var DataToSend = {};
if(startTotalTimeAndDate != undefined)
   DataToSend.startDateAndTime= startTotalTimeAndDate;
if(endTotalTimeAndDate!= undefined)
   DataToSend.endDateAndTime= endTotalTimeAndDate;
if(studentIdSelected!= undefined)
   DataToSend.studentId= studentIdSelected;
if(staffIdSelected!= undefined)
   DataToSend.staffId= staffIdSelected;

$.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:58371/api/ScheduleDateAndTime',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(DataToSend),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("You have assigned staff member " + staffSelected + " to student " + studentSelected + " on " +  datePickerValue   + " starting at " + startTime + " and ending at "  + endTime);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError + " have you checked that you have selected a date in the calander?\n Please ensure all fields have been correctly entered");
                }
            });
```